# What are these spurious lines when using geometry package?

Tags: geometry, crop

The finished book size is 170mm x 240mm.
The continuous black rectangle shows the boundary around the text only.
What is causing the two extra separate lines to appear at the side and bottom?
Also, is it possible to show the A4 page on which the logical page is sitting so that the crop marks can be seen?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{
    paperwidth=170mm,
    paperheight=240mm,
    lmargin=12.5mm,
    rmargin=12.5mm,
    bindingoffset=12.5mm,
    bottom=12mm,
    nohead
    }
\usepackage[cam,center,dvips]{crop} %
\begin{document}
\parindent=0mm
Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random. Some ran

\vspace{58mm}
Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random. Some ran

\vspace{58mm}
Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random. Some ran

\vspace{58mm}
Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random. Some ran

\clearpage

Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random. Some ran

\vspace{58mm}
Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random. Some ran

\vspace{58mm}
Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random. Some ran

\vspace{58mm}
Some random text. Some random text. Some random text. Some random. Some ran

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the `showframe` option of `geometry`. Remove it for the final version.

Comment: @Bernard - I understand crop marks protrude slightly from the corners of the page indicating the finished page. How can I get them to show?

Comment: \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[cam,center,dvips]{crop} %
\geometry{
 paperwidth=170mm,
 paperheight=240mm,
 lmargin=12.5mm,
 rmargin=12.5mm,
 bindingoffset=12.5mm,
 bottom=12mm,
 nohead
 }
%

Comment: @john Kormylo - The above changes cured the problem but, as you can see, it is not what the package says, is it?  For example, I've not included show crop.  And I still have the spurious lines.

Comment: If you mean the lines at the side and bottom, those are for the footer and \marginpar area. You can remove them by replacing nohead with noheadfoot and nomarginpar.  To see the crop marks, you need to set the paper size in crop LARGER then the paper size in geometry or documentclass.

Comment: To show crop marks using geometry the layoutwidth etc. needs to be smaller than the paperwidth etc.  Alas, no automatic centering.

Comment: @john Kormylo - many thanks.  My biggest mistake, I think, was that I could not get \crop to accept A4 pagesize - it demands a4 with a small a.  All fine now.

Comment: @john Kormylo - I cannot see how to accept your answer/advice since there is no tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra lines are from the footer and marginpar area, hence noheadfoot and nomarginpar in geometry.  To see crop marks you need to specify a larger size paper in crop than in geometry.  And since I use pdflatex instead of dvips...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\geometry{
    paperwidth=170mm,
    paperheight=240mm,
    lmargin=12.5mm,
    rmargin=12.5mm,
    bindingoffset=12.5mm,
    bottom=12mm,
    noheadfoot,
    nomarginpar
    }
\usepackage[cam,center,pdflatex,a4]{crop}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only

\parindent=0mm
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Could you please add an explanation what your answer does to fix the problem? It's not even clear that it is inspired from the comment section, if it is. The "You could submit your own answer" isn't clear to me, as well.

Comment: john Kormylo's answer cleared-up two confusions for me: (I) the geometry package refers to the logical page (the finished book size), whereas (ii) the crop package refers to the size of the paper on which it is printed.  That the crop package demands a4 rather than A4 is also a surprise (to me).  The "spurious" lines are not highlighted very well in the geometry documentation either.